# How to increase the loss if the predicted value is less than the label but not if it is greater

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I use an ai model to make a prediction of a value using mse. Do to noise in the data set, it is impossible for the model to ever give a perfect prediction. What I want to do is if there are two predictions equidistant from a label I want the lower prediction to be assigned a greater loss compared to the greater one. Essentially I want the model to be more likely to overshoot the value than to undershoot.

I assume this is done when compiling a model.

How would I modify this code segment used to compile my model to accomplish this?

```
genModel.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['mae', 'mean_squared_logarithmic_error'])
```

Comment: You need to supply your own loss function, rather than using a pre-defined one.  Call `compile` with that function as the loss parameter.  I assume you can continue from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom loss function according the [api reference](https://keras.io/api/losses/#creating-custom-losses) and compile your model with it. If you are using tenserflow you can refer to its [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py) of mean squared error loss and modify it according to your need.